# Upgrading internal hard drive to 2 terabyte on Windows 7, do I need GPT/UEFI?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, mbr

I'm currently trying to upgrade my PC from a 1 TB hard drive to a 2 TB one. I've been through a lot of pain so far, but I hope I'm near the end of it. What I want:

- All of my data on my 1 TB moved to my 2 TB
- Boot from the 2 TB, use it as the primary drive
- Access all 2 TB (exluding reserved storage)

Basically, I want my computer to have double the storage but otherwise act exactly as it did before.

Now, the current 1 TB of course uses the MBR partition style. I'm currently being asked by windows what partition style I should use for the new drive. I've been reading up on GPT vs MBR, and it seems like anything over 2 TB should use GPT. My questions are:

1. Since this is 2 TB and not OVER 2 TB, should I use GPT?
2. If so, won't that mean I need to use UEFI in order to use it for booting?

It sounds like if I need to use UEFI, I basically will have to convert my firmware, which is unsafe because I don't have yet another large hard drive lying around to put my existing files on in case it goes bad, and I don't feel like buying another smaller hard drive to make that work right now. Shame on me for thinking this would be straightforward :(

Comment: You cannot convert your firmware to UEFI.  If you don't have it then your hardware cannot use GPT.

Comment: Good to know! But it doesn't really answer either of my questions...

EDIT: Also, http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14286.converting-windows-bios-installation-to-uefi.aspx

Comment: @Ramhound, UEFI isn't required to use GPT, or even to boot from a GPT disk.  *Windows* is unable to boot from GPT disks on non-UEFI systems, though it can still use them for storage.  Linux can boot from GPT disks even on non-UEFI systems (you just have to create a tiny "BIOS boot partition" to install GRUB in).

Comment: @Wyzard - User is using Windows, not Linux, so my comment is accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer your question, just an insight in to my hard drive setup...

C:\ 750GB SSD, single drive

D:\ 512GB SSD RAID 1, My Documents to prevent losing data if I need to wipe C:\ clean.

E:\ 1.5TB Mechanical RAID 1, old mass-storage.

F:\ 4.0TB Mechanical RAID 1, newer mass-storage.

I also have a spare 128GB SSD left over from a non-paying ex-client. I've used it to test various Windows Updates and other things I don't trust though can't work with well in a virtual environment. If things take over well I switch back to my 750GB SSD. In the event that Windows gets screwed up I can always temporarily migrate my games to say the 4TB, wipe the 750GB drive and then simply clone from the 128GB to the 750GB; with the AppData folder in the My Documents folder (MS started calling it "User Files" because who cares about consistency?!) all the user preferences remain untouched as long as the user's My Document is pointed to D:\ on my system. In short: instead of three days to get my system back up and running (I have VERY specific setup and use my system for everything from gaming, movies, web development, the whole nine-yards) it just takes me about half an hour to clone. I'll slip the 128GB SSD like a floppy in the front 5.25 to 2.5+3.5 converter on the front of my case and flip the switch on or off.

---

You don't necessarily need to worry about which mode you're booting if you're just switching drives.

I shelled out money for Paragon's Hard Disk Manager, besides the goofy attempt to emulate Microsoft's Metro disaster (you can permanently disable it) it works great and I'll clarify some of the reasons why...

1. Microsoft's Disk Manager doesn't properly handle partitions and will always leave small amounts of unused space.
2. You can clone one drive to another and as long as you're cloning from a smaller drive to a larger drive it is extremely fast, about 30-60 minutes. Unfortunately it's a pain when going from a large drive to a small drive; you have to move enough files off to reduce the partition size (obviously the data remains though may have to be moved, bit fuzzy on that point) and then you can clone from a 2TB to a 1TB for example.

If you're concerned about the 2.1TB limitation don't be. A "2 TB" drive is 2,000,000,000,000 bytes. Windows calls that 1.82 (or so) TB. The true limit for MBR partitioning is at what Windows would call 2.0 TB. In hard drive labels this would be about a 2.2 TB drive. You will need GPT partitioning with a larger drive than that.

Paragaon's Disk Manager literally clones MBR (Master Boot Record) and other characteristics of the original drive to the newer drive. I'd love to suggest a freeware program and I'm sure they have a free version though sometimes it's worth spending money on good software.

Comment: Thank you so much for a great response! Sounds like I'll tell Windows to make it an MBR drive then. I hope I can get it working and get all of this behind me soon.

Comment: If were on the subject of cloning, I successfully used acronis true image to move my windows 7 system drive to a ssd plugged to it via a USB sata adapter. After the cloning finished, I swapped out the hard disk and put the ssd in the laptop. It worked well for the most part. Acronis resized the partition to take all the space of the bigger ssd. Only issue was that some of my paid software asked for serial number since the software seemed to know I was using a new hard drive. Other paid software didn't seem to care I switched to a new hard drive.

Comment: @sunk818 Yeah when you're doing a one-time need it's best to find a free solution but then eventually you find out that it wasn't going to be a one-time need.

Comment: @GregMartin One other nice thing is that once installed the program is portable which I highly prefer, gets you around third-party junk that wants to install on about half the installers (Ask, Chrome, Bing Bar, toolbars, etc). You're welcome and good luck! :-)

Comment: I think clonezilla is free. Even if the partition is the same on the bigger drive, it is easy to resize to the right from windows disk managment

Comment: @sunk818 True but I don't have time to restart my computer for every little process. If restarting your computer to clone a partition isn't a big deal than Clonezilla might work (never bothered after I found out it won't run on Windows but as a stand-alone boot device). That would would great if Windows died on you and you want to clone in that fashion in certain circumstances (not sure if it'll delete your files during install though that was an XP concern, you REALLY have to muck things up with 7+ to have it delete My Documents (but it DOES happen still if rarely).

Comment: @John afaik, the reason Windows Disk Manager "always leaves small amounts of unused space" (really _almost_ always) is: Partitions are supposed to start on cylinder boundaries, so that they can be described via CHS as well as LBA. Cylinders are of variable size these days, so this would seem pointless. But each drive has an advertised cylinder size which is supposed to be used to determine where partitions should start. If you start a partition somewhere else, diskmgmt.msc wlil add padding so you're not breaking the rule. 99% of systems don't care about this rule any more, but there it is.